# Editor different to final product

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, dreamweaver

I would like my div classes (.background_header, .background_content, .background_footer) to stack on top of each other during editing. In the link below you can see they stack fine, with the height of the header at 100vh and the content at 85vh, and the footer at 50vh.

http://www.hosting-mate.com/downloads/img1.png

In the image below however, when I want to edit it in dreamweaver, it displays COMPLETELY differently! I have tried setting the class position values to "relative" but that still doesnt work.

http://www.hosting-mate.com/downloads/img2.png

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #191919;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>

<!-- Content starts here -->

<body>

<div class="background_header">
    <div id="header_bg">
        <div id="border_l"><img src="http://www.hosting-mate.com/dkselectricalanddata/_assets/border_left_light.png" /></div>
        <div id="logo"><a href="http://www.dkselectricalanddata.com.au/"><img src="http://www.hosting-mate.com/dkselectricalanddata/_assets/logo_color_sml.png" /></a></div>
        <div id="border_r"><img src="http://www.hosting-mate.com/dkselectricalanddata/_assets/border_right_light.png" /></div>
        <div id="scroll"><img src="http://www.hosting-mate.com/dkselectricalanddata/_assets/scroll.png" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="background_content">
    <div id="content_bg">
        <div id="border_content_top"><img src="http://www.hosting-mate.com/dkselectricalanddata/_assets/content_border_top.png" /></div>
        <div id="form"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="background_footer">
    <div id="footer_bg">
        <div id="border_footer_top"><img src="http://www.hosting-mate.com/dkselectricalanddata/_assets/footer_border_top.png" /></div>
        <div id="icons"><img src="http://www.hosting-mate.com/dkselectricalanddata/_assets/icon_phone.png" /><img src="http://www.hosting-mate.com/dkselectricalanddata/_assets/icon_email.png" /></div>
        <div id="text"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

<!-- Content ends here -->
</html>
```

Below is my stylesheet code

```
@charset "utf-8";

img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}
.background_header {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
}


.background_content {
    height: 85vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    z-index: 50;
}

.background_footer {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    z-index: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
/* Header Content Starts*/
#header_bg {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#border_l {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    right: 75%;
    width: 25%;
    bottom: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    top: 37%;
    bottom: 35%;
    text-align: center;
}
#border_r {
    position: absolute;
    left: 75%;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    width: 25%;
    bottom: 50%;
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: right;
}
#scroll {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
}
/* Header Content Ends */



/* Form Content Starts */
#content_bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
/* Form Content Ends */



/* Footer Content Starts */
#footer_bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/* Footer Content Ends */}
```

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please insert the code in your question. We cannot help you if all we have is an image of your code - just copy and paste it into your code.

Comment: Looking at it now, try to upload images to a picture sharing site and then use the url as an img source.

Comment: This is the site on my test server and what it is meant to look like.

http://www.hosting-mate.com/dkselectricalanddata/

Comment: Updated links with links to the images on my server

I have other code on the style sheet for mobile phone and tablet use, however I haven't yet started playing with that. Trying to get the desktop working right first.

Comment: Dreamweaver's rendering engine is, and always has been, very poor. It's a very basic webkit clone and should not be used for actual design work. When in doubt...use a browser...preferably several.